# Is it possible to create shell scripts that push only a few of the locally accumulated commit?

Tags: git, shell, auto

I want to use a shell script to automatically push only a certain number of commits remote.
auto push works well, but what I want to do is, I want to manually git add and git commit and I want to automate push only.

For example, if there are 3 commits in the local area, push the oldest commit 3 and commit 2 and leave the latest commit 1.

```
git-auto.sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

baseDir = ~/dev/git-playground
cd ${baseDir}
afewCommits=`git commit | head -n 2` <- don't know how

if [ -z "$afewCommits" ]; then
    echo '##### file not found #####'
    exit
fi

git push
```

help me please

Comment: git push origin HEAD^:master

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- determine the name of your current branch
- push it (minus HEAD: the most recent commit) to its upstream branch of the same name:

```sh
branch-name = "!git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"
pub = "!f(){ git push -u origin HEAD^:$(git branch-name); };f"
```